# Python 3: How can I take a value in a variable and convert that to a unicode character?

Tags: python, unicode, variable-assignment

I'm trying to take a value and turn it into a unicode character, either by name or by value.  Every example I've seen has values hard-coded into the strings (like q = '\uc3a8') but that's not really helpful for me.  I'm getting some numerical or literal name input into variables.  I just can't figure out how to make it go.  I've tried various iterations of encode, decode, eval, r-strings, f-string, and I've got nothing.  What am I missing?  This is in Python 3.10.

```
LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_E_WITH_GRAVE = 0xC3A8
j = LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_E_WITH_GRAVE
print (j, "\u%04x" % j)
```

However, when I run it, I get this:

```
    print (j, "\u%04x" % j)
                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Similarly, if I do something like this:

```
char_name = "LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE"
z = "\N{" + char_name + "}"
```

I get this:

```
    z = "\N{" + char_name + "}"
              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: malformed \N character escape
```

Comment: You just want `chr(j)`.  All of your attempts are failing because you're trying to dynamically create a string escape sequence that is only meaningful when written literally in your source code.

Comment: @jasonharper is correct, you should just use the python built-in chr(): https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr

Comment: The problem with chr() is that it's limited to two-byte characters, and I have a few three-bytes:

    print (chr(0xE284A2))
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)
....
...
...
Oh.  Well,  OK.  I guess the code I'm converting has some crazy values in it that I'm just going to have to account for and do some sensible lookups.  Can't put 3 bytes of value in a 2-byte bag!

Comment: That is **not** a valid unicode code point: [The Unicode Standard defines a codespace,a set of numerical values ranging from 0 through 10FFFF16, called code points and denoted as U+0000 through U+10FFFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Codespace_and_Code_Points).

Comment: `0xC3E8` is *not* the Unicode code point for `è`.  The *bytes* `C3 E8` are `è` encoded as UTF-8.  `U+00E8` is the Unicode code point.  Use `chr(0xe8)`.  From bytes use `bytes([0xc3,0xa8]).decode()` or `b'\xc3\xa8'.decode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt, which may be helpful for you.
If you take the number after the hexadecimal indicator '0x' which is C3A8, you can display the information about the Unicode character and then assign it to a variable in the following way:

```
import unicodedata


def unicode_test(value):
    name = unicodedata.name(value)
    value2 = unicodedata.lookup(name)

    print('value="%s", name="%s", value2 = "%s"' % (value, name, value2))
    return value


character_wanted = unicode_test('\uC3A8')
```

Output:

```
value="쎨", name="HANGUL SYLLABLE SSYEOL", value2 = "쎨"
```

Of course, what the comments are suggesting you do above using the chr method is completely correct as well. They will give you the same result I believe, it just depends on the inputs that you are intending to use:

```
print(character_wanted, chr(0xC3A8))
```

Output:

```
쎨 쎨
```

Code snippet from the book *Introducing Python* by Bill Lubanovic, p. 148.

Comment: Thanks!  unicodedata.lookup(name) was exactly what I wanted!